# What happens when a wave reflects in water?

Tags: waves

The question is that the waves reflect in which style: [image]

It has two choices, 1)
[image]

2. [image]

Based on the below logic I believed that the answer is 1 : [image] as what if have learned when the wave goes through the water the angle should become smaller based on this formula : $$n_1.Sinx_1=n_2.Sinx_2$$ why doesn't it work here?

But a teacher said the answer is 2, the teacher didn't cite any reason, and I don't know why my logic is wrong and the answer becomes 2. Could you please explain which choice is true and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this problem we are analysing the refraction, in which the wave travels from one medium to another. First we need to see which medium has a higher (or smaller) refractive index. Since waves are faster in deep water, and $n$ is inversely proportional to $v$, $n_1$ will be smaller than $n_2$.

And, using the formula we see that: $$Sin(x_2)=Sin(x_1)\cdot a$$ where $a=\frac{n_1}{n_2}$ and $ 0<a<1 $, so $ Sin(x_2) $ is indeed smaller than $ Sin(x_1) $ . Because the angle is measured with respect to the normal of the surface, this means the angle will become smaller. Thus, the answer will be number 2.

Here is a little drawing of how the situation goes:[image]

Answer (score 1):

Water waves travel slower in shallow water, so the effective refractive index is higher. This means that "2" is correct as your drawing with the angles shows.  For some reason you have drawn the *ray direction*  in the shallow water rather than the *wavefronts* which are at right angles to the ray.